# Lightsail error: not authorized when logged in to root account

Tags: amazon-lightsail

I've been using Lightsail with the same account for over 2 years now. I have been running 3 instances without any issues, up to now. I had to reboot one of the instances, but I got an error "It looks like you aren't authorized". I'm using the root acccount, not an IAM account (but I tried to make one and that didn't work either). I'm logged into the root account that I've also used to create and manage all the instances in the past. So I don't see why I wouldn't be authorized. I'm not late on payments, and I don't have any errors or other issues anywhere that I know of.

I also tried to just create a new instance (I thought it may have been a problem related to the instance itself), but this gave me an error: "Sorry, you've reached your maximum limit of Lightsail Instances : 0". I have 3 instances, 2 of which are currently running and still accessible. Could this be a setting somewhere that I've missed? Or is this more likely to be an issue with my account that needs to be fixed on Amazon's end?